# DJI - Flight controller emulation

Tags: android, emulation, dji-sdk

I am trying to create an android application that can receive commands for drones from a server.

I have bug and I can not really debug it due to the fact that I need to keep my android phone connected to the DJI Flight Controller why I use the simulator, thus I can't see the variable values and log messages.

How can I solve this? Is there a way to emulate the DJI Flight Controller?

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use adb over wifi to debug your app thats connected to remote controller. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Bridge app tutorial provided by DJI sdk link: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/BridgeAppDemo.html
By using debug-Id of Bridge app  which shows on this app and place this id in your app code.Using this you can easily debug your app.But sometimes it giving crash so  i  consulted with DJI SDK team on GitHub .They are solving the crash for iOS but you can use same procedure in Android also.

Answer (score 0):

If you test on the phantom 3 standard ($500), you can run the log on your computer and connect your drone to the simulator. That way you can run logs on both devices. Another potential solution would be a usb splitter so that you can connect to computer and rc controller- but I am not sure that works because you may not be able to connect to both devices (I haven't tested.)